# How can I wrap a StaggeredGridView and a Row inside a Scrollable widget?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a StaggeredGridView which is scrolling properly when I don't wrap it in any other Widget. But when I'm trying to use it inside a Listview as I have more rows to be added under this gridview, the page is not scrolling.

Comment: Have you tried using a SingleChildScrollView instead?

Comment: I tried using SingleChildScrollView also. But it's not working @scottstoll2017

Comment: At this point I would suggest trying to contact @slightfoot or zoechi. I wish I could offer more but I'm traveling until Sunday. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used SliverStaggeredGrid.count as sliver Widget inside CustomScrollView which solved the problem.